# Different result when running command from terminal or from AppleScript

Tags: applescript

When I run `defaults read 'com.apple.Safari'` in terminal, I get a whole lot of information, especially the value I'm interested in: `defaults read 'com.apple.Safari' 'NSWindow Frame BrowserWindowFrame'`.

But when running in AppleScript, the result is completely different:

```
do shell script "defaults read 'com.apple.Safari'"
(*
{
    ResetCloudHistory = 1;
    cloudBookmarksMigrationEligibilityDataInvalidated = 1;
}
*)
```

So when I run the AppleScript asking for the key I'm interested in, I get the error message:

```
The domain/default pair of (com.apple.Safari, NSWindow Frame BrowserWindowFrame) does not exist
```

I assume this is due to security.

Does anyone know a way I can make my applescript access this setting **and** later write to it?

P.S. Using Mac OS 10.14 Mojave

Comment: On Sierra, I get the same output using either method (except the line endings are CR when generated by the applescript). I get identical results when asking for the key. Please include what OS you're running as that's been the source of many changes where applescript is concerned.

Comment: When testing with **Script Editor** in **macOS Catalina** I get the same output between it and **Terminal** for those `default` _commands_. What version of **macOS** are you using?

Comment: Updated above: Using 10.14 Mojave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read the *sandboxed* version of **com.apple.Safari.plist** in **macOS Mojave** from **Script Editor**, you need to add **Script Editor** to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**.

Then:

```
do shell script "defaults read 'com.apple.Safari' 'NSWindow Frame BrowserWindowFrame'"
```

Returns, e.g.,:

```
"88 73 1264 804 0 0 1440 877 "
```

Note that if the `do shell script` *command* is run by some other *method*, then the *application* involved in that *method* would need to be added to: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Full Disk Access**

---

In **macOS Mojave**, to see the difference, from **Terminal**:

```
$ defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist 
{
    IncludeDevelopMenu = 1;
    WebKitDeveloperExtrasEnabledPreferenceKey = 1;
    "WebKitPreferences.developerExtrasEnabled" = 1;
}
$


$ defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist 'NSWindow Frame BrowserWindowFrame'
88 73 1264 804 0 0 1440 877 
$
```

However, the same later *command* using the `do shell script` *command*:

```
do shell script "defaults read 'com.apple.Safari' 'NSWindow Frame BrowserWindowFrame'"
```

It is obviously accessing the *sandboxed* version of **com.apple.Safari.plist**, based on what's returned.